# How to create a table from remote database using dblink

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl, dblink

How to create a table from remote database using dblink

```
create table MYTABLE@DBLINK (name varchar2(20)));
```

> ***Cause**:    An attempt was made to use a DDL operation on a remote database.
> For example, "CREATE TABLE tablename@remotedbname ...".
>
> ***Action**:   To alter the remote database structure, you must connect to the
> remote database with the appropriate privileges.

Is this a privilege error or it is not possible to do with dblink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you managed to create a database link, you obviously have that user's credentials so the simplest option is to actually connect as *remote user* and create table in that schema directly.

If you want to do it from your schema, you can't do it using that syntax, but - there's a workaround: `dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement`

Here's an example.

Database link first:

```
SQL> create database link dbl_mike connect to mike identified by lion using '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my_server)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)))';

Database link created.
```

Does it work? Yes!

```
SQL> select * from dual@dbl_mike;

D
-
X
```

This is what you tried, and found out that it won't work:

```
SQL> create table test_dbl@dbl_mike (id number);
create table test_dbl@dbl_mike (id number)
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02021: DDL operations are not allowed on a remote database
```

Workaround I mentioned:

```
SQL> exec dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@dbl_mike('create table test_dbl (id number)');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Testing (if table exists, I can insert a row over database link and select from that table):

```
SQL> insert into test_dbl@dbl_mike (id) values (100);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test_dbl@dbl_mike;

        ID
----------
       100

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If you have several statements to run, you can do it one-by-one using `exec`. Note that it won't work *everywhere*; it works in SQL*Plus, SQL Developer and perhaps some other tools. But, as it is *short* for a `BEGIN-END` block, you could rather/better

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@dbl_mike('create table test_dbl (id number)');
  3    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@dbl_mike('create table test_dbl2 (id number)');
  4  end;
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: if i need to create multiple tables should i write multiple statements exec dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@dbl_mike('create table test_dbl (id number)');  exec dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement@dbl_mike('create table test_dbl2 (id number)');  also for adding sequence and for adding constraints should i follow the same way

Comment: Have a look at edited answer; it contains example.

Comment: Can i check if a table exists drop it first before creating a table.

Comment: how do i check if a table exists drop it first before creating a table

Comment: Query USER_TABLES or USER_OBJECTS (where USER_TYPE is equal to TABLE).